# On Debian bookworm 12.5 , how to replace/switch the desktop manager used by xrdp from cinnamon to gnome?

Tags: debian, gnome, xrdp

When installing debian on computer,
if choosing to install several desktop managers including gnome and cinnamon,
when then installing xrdp,
despite the default desktop manager is Gnome,
xrdp is choosing cinnamon by default for remote sessions
and I do not manage to change it.

I tried to copy the config file dynamically generated in the user home:
`cp .xsessionrc .xsession`,
in the aim to change the configuration,
but it just prevents the remote connexion to occur..

How should one do ?